# Aggregate values and display in chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2016

I am struggling with this problem and I can't figure out how to solve it.

This is my dataset detail data:

```
Order  Item    StartDay      EndDay     EndYear  StartEndDiff
 1      1     01.01.2018   02.01.2018    2018         1
 1      2     03.01.2018   05.01.2018    2018         2
 2      1     05.01.2019   06.01.2019    2019         1
 2      2     06.01.2019   06.01.2019    2019         0
 2      3     08.01.2019   10.01.2019    2019         1
 3      1     07.01.2019   08.01.2019    2019         1
```

I now group them by `Order` (this works fine in a tablix). Group name is `OrderGroup`:

```
Order   MinStartDay   MaxEndDay    EndYear  MinStartMaxEndDiff
 1      01.01.2018    05.01.2018    2018        4
 2      05.01.2019    10.01.2019    2019        5
 3      07.01.2019    08.01.2019    2019        1
```

For `MinStartMaxEndDiff` I got the following expression:

```
=DateDiff("d", Min(Fields!StartDay.Value, "OrderGroup"), Max(Fields!EndDay.Value, "OrderGroup"))
```

Now I added another group in the tablix and displayed the `Avg(MinStartMaxEndDiff)` per `EndYear`. This still works fine in the tablix with all the groupings. The result:

```
Avg(MinStartMaxEnd)    Year
       4               2018
       3               2019
```

But I can't figure out how to display only the data from the result, based on the calculations, in a chart. I normally do these calculations on the SQL side, but this time I can't do them SQL side.

The problem is when I try to add the `OrderGroup` in the chart it always shows me the details. But I need this group to get the right values. Hide or set the category label to `Nothing` didn't work. Also setting the `DataElementOutput`to `NoOutput` didn't help (real look):

[image: Actual Look]

I would just need on the x-axis the `Years` and as values the `Avg(MinStartMaxEnd)`. This would be my desired output based on the sample data from above:

[image: Desired Look]

**EDIT AFTER A SOLUTION WAS FOUND:**

What can I do if a row data looks like this:

```
Order  Item    StartDay      EndDay     EndYear  StartEndDiff
 1      1     29.12.2018   02.01.2019    2019         4
 1      2     28.12.2018   30.12.2018    2018         2
```

This one will get divided into two separate datarows in the tablix, because of the `EndYear` grouping. The expected result should be look like this:

```
Order   MinStartDay   MaxEndDay    EndYear  MinStartMaxEndDiff
 1      28.12.2018    02.01.2019    2019        5
```

But a grouping of the year with the expression

```
=Max(CDate(Fields!EndYear.Value), "OrderGroup")
```

is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom code inside your tablix to calculate the average per year, and call the calculated values in the chart.

Add the following custom code to your report

```
Public Dim YearAvg As New System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String , Decimal )

Public Function SetYearAverage( ByVal s As String,  ByVal d AS Decimal) As Decimal
YearAvg.Add(s,d)
Return d

End Function
```

In the textbox you calculate the year average change the expression to the following (make the appropriate changes to field names)

```
= Code.SetYearAverage(Cstr(Fields!EndYear.Value), Avg ( DateDiff("d", Min(Fields!StartDay.Value,"OrderId"), Max(Fields!EndDay.Value,"OrderId"))))
```

Then set your chart expression to

```
=   Code.YearAvg( Cstr( Fields!EndYear.Value))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This actually worked :-) Thanks, I already thought this wouldn´t be possible. One problem is left. I edit my question with this one. Maybe you have a solution for this as well.

Comment: You are welcome. The changes in requirements needs a different approach in custom code - if possible. Not very sure If I ll make it.

Comment: That would be awesome but no worries, at the moment I can live with a few of these blurs.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer as I didn't get the results you were expecting, work got in the way! However, it's fairly close so I thought I would post it in case it was any help.

A pity doing this on the server was not an option as it would be really easy.

Anyway, I replicated your dataset (with a couple of field name changes to avoid keyword conflicts) and set the chart up as follows..

Category groups - None

Series Groups 2. Parent group is on 'EndYear' called 'ChartYearGroup', child group is on OrderID called 'ChartOrderGroup'

Values - Here I set the Category Field to `[EndYear]` and the expression was

```
=AVG(DateDiff(
    "d"
    , Min(Fields!StartDay.Value, "ChartOrderGroup")
    , Max(Fields!EndDay.Value, "ChartOrderGroup")
    )
    , "ChartYearGroup"
    )
```

This does give the correct numbers but unfortunately shows per order rather than per year.

I'm not sure if this will be possible to resolve. Somehow I guess you'll have to hide the order group or combine the two groups into one, I just ran out of time to test.

Here's the end result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Yep this is exactly the point where I keep ending up every time as well. I also thought about a option to `hide Odergroup` in the diagram but didn´t find one. If you change now my sample dataset with the real data, you will get the first image I posted. But I think I agree with you that this isn´t possible

Comment: If I get time, I'll take a another look but my gut feeling is that you won;t be able to do this.. One thing I did think of, but didn't try was seeing if you could set colours all the same and dynamically adjusting the point width so the end results would look correct. So based on the simple dataset, 2018 would be 100/1 and 2019 would be 100/2 giving two 50% columns stuck together